# Can't get size of an ExtendedState JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm not able to get the size of a JFrame. The JFrame has been maximized with setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH) and it is also visible.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Fenster extends JFrame {

    Fenster() {

        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(this.getWidth() + " x " + this.getHeight());

    }

}
```

I only get "0 x 0" or "1 x 1" in the console. And I also dont know why the  output is random.

Comment: I get it right 1366 x 768. I have copied your code.

Comment: I tested it with JRE7-openjdk-7.u75_2.5.4-1 on Arch Linux with Gnome3.

Comment: *'I'm not able to get the size of a JFrame."*  Why do you want that dimension?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 2):

JFrame.pack() is called after setExtendedState which may resize the JFrame (others comment not to experience this issue, so it may be environment based). I can reproduce what you observe on a Mac - if pack() is removed or setExtendedState called after pack() the behavior seems more in tune with what I believe you want.

Comment: And if the person adds no components then the frame is set to the smallest possible, being 0x0 or 1x1

Comment: True. I was hoping this was mainly for demo purposes. That being said even with components added, what I observe is that without moving the call to setExtendedState the dimensions (eg full screen) does not occur.

Comment: Yeah he's gotta move that pack()

Comment: But without pack() I get the same result. So what shoud I do to get the size of the window.

By the way: On Gnome3, the application doesn't cover the taskbar. So I'm not able to use the screen dimension (?)

Comment: I'm confused - are you just trying to get the screen dimensions?

Comment: I wanna make a fullscreen game which is using custom paintings.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int w = getSize().getWidth();
int h = getSize().getHeight();
```

I don't know why your code does not work

Comment: Same problem. I already tried this. I also tried
this.getContentPane().getSize().getHeight() but it didn't worked either.

Comment: Then it is probably due to the fact that you called pack with no components in the frame

Comment: At first I didn't used pack(). But in an other question on SO, someone wrote that I have to use pack() and setVisible(true) before I'm able to get the size.

Comment: Pack just shrinks the frame to the minimum size and isn't required